# The circuit breaker does not stay on after lightning!

Tags: lightning

After lightning, one of the circuit breakers does not stay on. The breaker is connected to 4 different sets of lights in living /dining room. All receptacle are working in that area (connected to different circuit breaker). I am not sure if lightning hit my house or not, but it was very close! I have thought it might be a bad breaker and replaced it but that did not help. I took one of the light fixtures out and tested by connecting it to different area and it was fine. It seems like a surge or a shortage somewhere!
Not an easy access to any wiring except the switches.
Any help will most appreciated!

Comment: What type of lights? Can you disconnect different sections to isolate the short?

Comment: They are all LED lights. Unfortunately I can not isolate them. They are all connected to the walls and ceiling. I have a 24 ft ceiling!

Comment: What make and model is the breaker panel, and did the old breaker have a TEST button on it?

Comment: The sticker on the panel says HOMELINE Load Center  model HOMC24UC. The breaker did not have a TEST button. It is a normal 15 Amp breaker (On / OFF).

Comment: Sounds like the breaker is protecting you from a short, and you need to isolate it. Beyond that, it isn't clear what we could suggest.

Comment: Think the same. One more thing to add. When I took the light fixture out, I checked with multi-meter and there was no resistance between the Neutral (white) wire and Ground wire. I do not know if that is the one causing the breaker to trip or not! Can I take the Ground wire out (disconnect) from the breaker and test  or not?

Comment: @MikeGryloo -- there should *not* be significant resistance from Neutral to Ground (they're connected by the bonding screw or strap in your main panel)

Comment: Thanks for the info! Do you guys recommend any specific tools that can help to locate the shortage . I have access to the light switches only the rest of wiring are inside the wall.